# Boundary of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We have a compact and convex subset $K\subseteq \mathbb R^n$. Also assume that $K$ has more than one point.

We want to show that a point $x\in K$ is not on the boundary of $K$ (that is $x\in \operatorname{int}(K)$).

We think that it is enough to show that there exists an interval $(x-ad,x+ad)$ that is contained entirely in $K$ (that is, we can find a straight line passing through $x$ that lies in $K$). In our case $a$ is nonzero and positive and $d\notin K$.

Can we deduce from the existence of such interval the existence of an entire open neighborhood $V$ such that $x\in V \subseteq K$?

Geometrically it looks correct. But we don't have a formal proof.
Any remarks would be appreciated!

Thank you!

**Edit**

After the discussion below, I see that in case the boundary contains a straight line, my argument is clearly false.

Comment: If $K=\{x\}$ it is certainly false.

Comment: If the point is on the border of K, with the border a plane, then you can have a segment in K, but the point on the border. You probably need strict convexity for this to works

Comment: If the border is a plane I do not think it can be compact, but with a closed cube Tryss suggestion should work as a counter example.

Comment: @GRF : yes, I meant "locally a plane" not a whole space plane, but thanks to add this precision  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In our case I'm not sure whether the boundary contains straight lines or doesn't. But when we take a line in the direction $d$ where $d$ is not in $K$, I think that it works...

Comment: @Ludolila Your argument will work if you manage to show that for *all* $d\in{\mathbb R}^n$ since for (nonempty) convex sets in ${\mathbb R}^n$ the algebraic interior coincides with the topological one.

Comment: @A.G. I see how it's true if I prove it for all $d$, but   I thought that maybe just one such $d$ would be enough...

Comment: @Ludolila Unfortunately not, one line is too thin to capture the "fat" property.

Comment: @Ludolila Counterexample as in the answer with $d=[2,0]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot deduce such a thing. For example, for $n=2$, you can take $K=[0,1]^2$.

Then, take the point $x=(\frac12, 0)$. You can find that the line $t\mapsto (t, 0)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ (i.e. the line from $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$) passes through $x$ and is contained entirely in $K$. Nonetheless, $x$ is not in the interior of $K$.

Comment: Thanks! It made me realize that I forgot to mention that $d$ is not in $K$.  Do you have an example for that case as well?

Comment: @Ludolila My example is such an example, since the line between $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ is the line between $x - \frac{1}{20} (10, 0)$ and $x + \frac{1}{20} (10, 0)$, and $d=(10,0)$ is not in $K$.

Comment: True, missed it :)